# c# quando pressionado ao mesmo tempo alt + f4 abre uma nova form

Tags: c#

Boa noite ou bom dia dependendo de onde vivem eu queria saber se algum de vocês poderiam dizer como posso abrir uma nova form quando pressionado ao mesmo tempo alt + f4

Comment: PQ você quer usar o Alt+F4 para abrir um novo formulário, certamente 99,9% das aplicações usa o Alt+F4 para fechar o formulário.

Comment: estou a fazer o alt f4 e isso é oque eu vou usar para passar para o próximo nivel ninguem vais suspeitar

Comment: @Pekira, ainda não ficou claro o sentido de utilizar essa funcionalidade, como o Pablo Vargas mesmo disse, essa funcionalidade é usada para fechar o formulário. Pode explicar melhor qual a finalidade desse recurso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para abrir um novo formulário ao clicar `alt+F4`:

**Formulário 1:**

1. Setar a propriedade `KeyPreview` como `true`;

   ```
      this.KeyPreview = true;
   ```
2. Assinar o evento KeyDown;

   ```
      this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
   ```
3. Completo;

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.KeyPreview = true;
      this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
   }
   private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if(e.Alt&&e.KeyCode==Keys.F4)
       {
          Form2 form2 = new Form2();
          form2.Show();
          e.Handled = true;
       }
   }
   ```

**Importante**

> Set a propriedade `e.Handled = true;`  para evitar que o formulário 2
>   feche.